# EPPlus not saving changes to worksheet

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I have a batch job that loops through a spreadsheet processing each record row by row. Depending on the results, I want to leave a comment in the last column of each record.

I can tell, by monitoring the value in this cell while the program's running, that the appropriate changes are going where they need to. However, after running the `.Save()` function I open the spreadsheet and each column looks the same as it did before the program was run.

It seems like they built [EPPlus](https://epplus.codeplex.com/) to be pretty straightforward with regard to saving your changes, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Here is how I open the spreadsheet

```
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    try
    {
        //Connect to spreadsheet
        FileStream _stream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);

    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        SendEmail.OkMail("Spreadsheet is currently in use. Please close and try again.");

        //Exit program
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    //Pull data into EPPlus object
    _package = new ExcelPackage();
    _package.Load(_stream);
    _sheet = _package.Workbook.Worksheets.First(); 
}
else
{
    //Notify user and exit program
    SendEmail.OkMail("Cannot find file in requested directory. Please check and try again.");

    //Exit program
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

This code makes the appropriate changes. While stepping through this part of the code, I can see that the right value is being stored in the correct cell of the `ExcelWorkSheet` object named `_sheet`

```
//Figure out what type of update occurred
if (ignore == (_noUpdates - 1))
{
    _sheet.Cells[row, col + 11].Value = "Ignore";
}
else if (add == (_adds - 1))
{
    _sheet.Cells[row, col + 11].Value = "Valid Add";
}
else if (update == (_updates - 1))
{
    _sheet.Cells[row, col + 11].Value = "Valid Update";
}
else if (autoterm == (_autotermed - 1))
{
    _sheet.Cells[row, col + 11].Value = "Valid Autoterm";
}
```

Once I'm done looping through the spreadsheet, I make this call to the `.Save()` function. Nothing happening here though. Changes are not being saved.

```
//Save changes to spreadsheet.
_package.Save();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `Load(Stream)` method doesn't store the path of the file, and doesn't store the passed-in stream to re-use when saving. When you call the `Save()` method, the package doesn't know where to save the file, and simply closes the package.

*(This seems like a bad design to me; it should probably throw an exception in this case.)*

Try changing your code to use the constructor which takes a `FileInfo` argument:

```
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(path);
if (file.Exists)
{
    try
    {
        _package = new ExcelPackage(file);
        _sheet = _package.Workbook.Worksheets.First();
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
        SendEmail.OkMail("Spreadsheet is currently in use. Please close and try again.");

        //Exit program
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }
}
else
{
    //Notify user and exit program
    SendEmail.OkMail("Cannot find file in requested directory. Please check and try again.");

    //Exit program
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: This worked great. Needed to get rid of the `FileStream` object though, as it looks like you've done in your code. thank you!!

Comment: I have FileInfo but it does not save.

Comment: @MuhammedYILMAZ Impossible to answer without seeing your code.It's also possible that this answer might no longer apply to the latest version of EPPlus, which has changed significantly.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65360811/i-use-epplus-in-aspnet-i-can-read-data-but-i-cannot-write-to-existing-file-fi?noredirect=1#comment115560956_65360811